# error Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chrome.exe"

Tags: java

He de hacer esto Crea y ejecuta un proceso (Process) de un programa con interfaz gráfica como, por ejemplo, Firefox tanto para Windows como para GNU/Linux. Usa la clase Runtime.
Segun he visto valia con poner start chrome en la consola de comandos por loque he hecho  este programita pero da error.

```
String comando;
        String s = null;
        comando = "chrome.exe";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        System.out.println("Ésta es la salida standard del comando:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        // Leemos los errores si los hubiera
        System.out.println("Ésta es la salida standard de error del comando (si la hay):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tu variable `comando` le debes indicar la ruta donde se encuentre el proceso, en este caso `chrome.exe`. Por ejemplo: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`.

Ademas, debes englobar tu código en un `try/catch` para encapsular errores que pudieran ocurrir.

Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class example {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String comando;
        String s = null;

        //ruta donde se encuentre chrome instalado en tu equipo.
        comando = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
        Process p;

        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            System.out.println("Ésta es la salida standard del comando:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            // Leemos los errores si los hubiera
            System.out.println("Ésta es la salida standard de error del comando (si la hay):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```